# Redirect on empty dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have the following route layout:

```
App.Router.map ->
    @resource('playbook', { path: '/playbook/:graph_id' }, ->
        @route('information')
        @resource('goals', { path: '/goals/:vertex_id' }, ->
            @route('tasks')
            @route('messages')
        )
    )
```

So a typical URL would look something like `#/playbook/12345/goals/6789/messages`. However, I want users to be able to go directly to `#/playbook` and be redirected to a relevant URL (I save the last one accessed). How can I redirect the user only if `:graph_id` is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `afterModel` hook in `PlaybookRoute` to check if the model is empty and redirect to the previous route.

```
afterModel: function(model) {
  if (model is empty) {
    this.transitionTo(stored route)
  }
}
```

Note: `transitionTo` expects resolved models if there are dynamic segments on the new route.

Comment: I like the mix of Javascript and Pseudocode. :p Thank you, I think this will do it. I'll try it out as soon as I get home tonight.

Comment: This worked, thanks. It should be noted, however, that you must redirect to a **route**, not a resource. Took me a while to figure that one out.